# unable to create role in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I am trying to create a new role in mongodb but It is giving me error:

```
> use Admin
switched to db Admin
> db.createRole( { role: "executeFunctions", privileges: [ { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] } ], roles: [] } );
2018-03-13T19:59:25.114+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Roles on the 'Admin' database cannot be granted privileges that target other databases or the cluster :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createRole@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1541:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: When you typed "use _Admin_", did you mean "use **admin**"? Database names are case-sensitive, so the two are very different.

Comment: yes. "use admin" it is strange think. It is working with "Admin"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time mongo work with the wrong spell and create the problem later.

So check:

```
use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createRole( { role: "executeFunctions", privileges: [ { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] } ], roles: [] } );
```